# how to input implode value checkbox one by one?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

now I have a problem with my input checkbox (with style switch). I want to implode the value of a checkbox but one by one. I'm using an ajax to input the data.

here's the image :

[image]

here's my input HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="switch-sesi{{ $sesi->id }}" name="status[]" value="{{ $sesi->id }}" class="switch-input">
```

here's my ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
   type:'GET',
   method: 'GET',
   url:'{{ url("setStatus/".Auth::user()->id."") }}',        
   data: {
        date:date,
        sesi_id:sesi_id,
   },
   success: function(result){
       console.log(result);
   }
});
```

here's my controller that handle the request :

```
public function setStatus(Request $req, $id)
    {   
        $consultant_id  =   Consultant::where('user_id', $id)->get();        
        if (!empty($consultant_id)) {            
            if (count(Schedule::where('date',$req->date)->get()) == 0) {                
                $input = Schedule::create([
                    'consultant_id' =>  $consultant_id[0]->id,
                    'sesi_id'       =>  $req->sesi_id,
                    'date'          =>  $req->date,
                ]);
                return 'it works!';
            }else{

> **this part what I have tried**

                $update = Schedule::where('date', $req->date)->update([
                    'sesi_id'       => implode('-', $req->sesi_id);
                ]);
            }            
        }else{
            return "gagal input";
        }
    }
```

the input is working fine, but the update still error. it always overwrite the previous `sesi_id`.
THERE IS NO input button or submit. So the thing is when I `checked/turn on` the input checkbox, I want to extend the `sesi_id` with the previous `sesi_id` using implode.

hope you guys understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating in the right way . 
You are updating only the request value in sesi_id.

Try implode before you update .

Comment: thank you for the response sir, but how do I get an array of `sesi_id` using ajax?

Comment: You can save in array with javascript and in PHP you loop with foreach .

Comment: ahhh... that's brilliant ok I'll try it!